# Ways to avoid serializing and deserializing a json when it's the output?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I have a method that calls an http request,
and I need to output it like it is,

Right now I'm testing the code so I used a ReadAsString which adds \n and \"

I would like to know what is the easiest way to return it to be shown by Ok, I'm not using on this code this information, it's just going through here so would love to avoid creating an object to support this.

The method that is being called

```
public async Task<String> GetGoogleLocation(string address){
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, string.Format(GeoCodeApi, address));
    var response = await this._proxy.SendAsync(request);
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

my endpoint:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> geoLocateAddress(){
    return this.Ok(await this._geoCodeService.GetGoogleLocation("Address"));
}
```

Comment: are you just proxying the response?

Comment: kind of, but that's the idea, it adds some parameters from the internal db and adds authorization keys arround

Comment: don't u wanna use something like this `return await Json.Decode(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());`  with return type as `Task<dynamic>`?

Comment: it says that json.decode doesn't exists in the context

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588652/web-api-2-return-content-with-ihttpactionresult-for-non-ok-response) solve your question? Also use geoLocateAddressAsync instead of geoLocateAddress

Comment: This has nothing to do with `async-await`, right?

Comment: no @JeroenHeier it doesn't, but thanks anyway

Comment: @PauloMorgado what do you mean? the code is working, I just want to find a better way to show the result without serializing the json which implies creating an structure that will never be used