# Web API2 ,How to return an error

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

```
public IHttpActionResult Save(item)
{
    try
    {
        result = MyRepository.Save(item);
        return Ok(result);
    }
    catch
    {
        // What should I do here?
        // I wish to return an error response how can i do that? 
    }
}
```

If it has no exception,I can return  Ok.

But if there is an exception what should I do?

**Note that I have javascript client**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning http status code from Web Api controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655350/returning-http-status-code-from-web-api-controller)

Comment: Or see [Return content with IHttpActionResult for non-OK response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588652/return-content-with-ihttpactionresult-for-non-ok-response). You want to return a non 200 status code to the caller, that is the accepted way to return errors.

Answer (score 1):

Create a model to hold what error information you want to return and pass that.

```cs
public IHttpActionResult Save(item) {
    try {
        result = MyRepository.Save(item);
        return Ok(result);
    } catch {
        // What should I do here? Create a model to hold the data you want to return
        var myErrorModel = new {
            code = "My custom error code or 500 server error code",
            message = "some friendly error message"
        };

        // I wish to return an error response how can i do that?
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, myErrorModel);
        return ResponseMessage(response);
    }
}
```

In your javascript client in the error handler you can then access the model properties and handle the error as you see fit.

```js
var handleResponse = function (data) {
    var code = data.code;
    var message = data.message
};
```

UPDATE:

Agreeing with @Win, I personally don't like doing this in the controller actions as it is a Cross-cutting concern and have basically moved everything from within the catch block into a global error handler.

Answer (score 1):

In Web API 2, you can use **BadRequest** to return an error message.

```
public IHttpActionResult Save(item)
{
    try
    {
        result = MyRepository.Save(item);
        return Ok(result);
    }
    catch
    {
        return BadRequest("Error message");
    }
}
```

***FYI:*** Do not use **try catch block** just to swallow an exception. I personally do not like using **try catch** block inside Action method. Instead, I let Web API 2 Global Exception Handler handles exceptions. It is the out of the scope of your original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpResponseException to send an error message.

```
public IHttpActionResult Save(item)
{
    try
    {
        result = MyRepository.Save(item);
        return Ok(result);
    }
    catch
    {
       var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(string.Format("Error Message!!"),
            ReasonPhrase = "Error Reason phrase"
        };
        throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `HttpResponseException` as below:

```
throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
```

Or another way is:

```
var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)  
    {  
        Content = new StringContent("some error"),  
            ReasonPhrase = "Not Found"  
    };  

    throw new HttpResponseException(response);
```