# Angular 6 error handlig - HttpErrorResponse has undefined status

Tags: json, angular, rest, error-handling, http-status-codes

I have a Angular 6 client consuming a REST Api developed with .Net Web Api.

Everything is working except for the error handling. When I try to process the error to react differently to different status codes (404, 403, 409, 500...) I simply can't make it work. The HttpErrorResponse object doesn't have any of the fields it is supposed to (like 'status' or 'error').

I've made a super simple service that reproduces the issue:

Request on the service.ts

```
 public test(): Observable<any> {
    let url = this.templatesUrl + '/myMethod';
    console.log('GET myMethod ' + url);

    return this.http.get<any>(url)
                      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

Error handler (pretty much straight from the official documentation):

```
 private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.warn(error);

    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
        `body was: ${error.message}`);
    }
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    return throwError('Unexpected error');
  }
```

Service on the .Net side:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("myMethod")]
public IHttpActionResult myDotNetMethod()
{
    return InternalServerError(new Exception("Details about the issue"));
}
```

The service is called and it returns a status code 500 along with a json object:

The status of the response:

[image: Chrome showing the request]

The response header, it is json:

[image: Response header, it is json]

The json object:

[image: The json object returned]

And what the log shows: no status and pretty much an empty object:

[image: What the log shows, no status and pretty much an empty object]

Loosk like the HttpErrorResponse is pretty much empty. But the response from the API was fine, the status code is there and the json object too.

What am I missing?

**Update:** In case you are wonder what hides behind that "Internal Server Error" that shows in the log (it is just the callstack generated by chrome):

[image]

**Update 2:** Here's the error object under the microscope. It is simply "Internal Server Error". No trace of status or message.

[image]

Comment: try to print whole error object in console and check status and message are there or not. some times it is `error.error.status` and `error.error.message`.

Comment: Ashish, I'm already printing the error object (first line in handleError). It contains... nothing (check the picture in the updated question).

Comment: can you set a breakpoint in your error handler method and check the value of the `error` argument? My guess is that the object passed isnt trully a `HttpErrorResponse` instance

Comment: try console.log once

Comment: Jota and Ashish, no luck. Check the updated question, that object is empty :_(

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Solved... the object was empty due to an interceptor. So if something similar is happening to you check those out.

I'm sorry to have wasted everyone's time, I was unaware of the existance of that particular interceptor.

Comment: No worries, glad you got it sorted out.

Comment: You saved me. I was facing same issue and issue was same interceptor

Comment: Great! I'm glad this can be helpful!

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is how you are throwing the error in .Net.
Try this:

```
var statusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

var response = new HttpResponseMessage(statusCode)
{
    Content = new ObjectContent<object>(
        new
        {
            Message = "Error Message",
            ExceptionMessage = "StackTrace"
        },
        new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())
};

throw new HttpResponseException(response);
```

Or if it does not work try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28589333/8758483

Another good idea is to centralize your error handling by implementing an ErrorHandler in Angular.

```
import { ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {  
  handleError(error) {
    // your custom error handling logic    
  }
}
```

Then you tell Angular you want to use this class instead of the default one by providing it in you NgModule:

```
@NgModule({   
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: GlobalErrorHandler}]
})
```

If you want more detail you can read this article:

- [Expecting the Unexpected — Best practices for Error handling in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/expecting-the-unexpected-best-practices-for-error-handling-in-angular-21c3662ef9e4)

Comment: Thanks Michael. I tried returning Content() but no luck. I have a centralized error handler + some specific error handlers for some scenarios. But I still have the same issue. I can recognize an error, but not the specific kind of error (status code, message...). I'll take a look at the article.

Comment: I found something in our solution that you can try out. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the response the property is called "Message" and not "message".

Comment: I don't think that the error.message and the Message property of the json response are the same. Right? Otherwhise what if the json object doesn't have that propery?

Comment: What do you see when you "open" the warn-log in the console?

Comment: It is just the callstack generated by chrome (check the pic in the updated question).